# izpack installer 'is not marked as executable' on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, installation, izpack

I created an installer that works fine on OS X and Windows. On Ubuntu I get the message "The file '/media/administrator/UNTITLED/installer.jar' is not marked as executable" when trying to right click and launch with Java.

It works after I set the executable bit, but that's not the experience I expect from an installer.

The installer was built on OS X and I also tried to preset the executable bit via ant chmod, but I assume that This is lost or prevented on Ubuntu for security reasons?

Is there a way to reliably preset the executable bit?
If not, are there alternative tools for creating double-clickable Installers that work on Ubuntu without users having to manually set permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer is "It's not possible. You need to create a .deb package to get the desired behaviour".

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the file and go properties, then select permissions and check "Allow executing file as program".

**EDIT:**
Or alternatively, set the jdk/jre as default program for .jar type. (this is one thing you can not control by your installer)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but as I wrote "It works after I set the executable bit",  So I know how to do that. If you read on, my problem is: "but that's not the experience I expect from an installer." So this is not a solution.

Comment: usually, OS disables such permission for downloaded file

Comment: Thanks, so do I have to create a .deb package to improve usability, or is there another way to give them a nicer user experience?

Comment: i doubt. as archive manager (an alternative way to 'open' the jar) is default with linux unlike jre. So may be you need to set default jar-handler to jre.

Comment: @ay89 This is a question about how to *package* software properly for distribution. Changing the default jar-handler on everyone's computer who downloads this *before* they download it is not possible. This question is not by an end user asking how to install software s/he downloaded. It is a question by a developer (posted on Stack Overflow) about how to package software for easy installation. This answer fundamentally does not address the question that was asked here.

Comment: well who uses linux new how to deal with that, and as such there is no alternative to that. **a down vote wont change this mechanism** Similarly having an applet on a webpage, you can not ensure everyone has jre. There is no other packaging alternative (only possible way is if you could create a .deb out of that jar)

Comment: Eliah Kagan's comment is correct, this question is clearly about packaging, not the client side. It seems the answer is: "It's not possible. You need to create a .deb package to get the desired behaviour." If you add that as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.